# Warning when adding Regularization to embedding layer

Tags: tensorflow, keras, embedding

When I add l2 Regularization to my Embedding for my categorical Data like so:

```
    emb_layer = []
    cat_dim = len(cat_ix)

    X = Input(shape=(cat_dim,))
    X_split = Lambda(lambda x: tf.split(x, cat_dim, 1))(X)
    
    for i in range(len(cat_ix)):
        cardinality = int(df[cat_ix[i]].nunique())
        embed_dim = int(min(np.ceil(cardinality/2),10))

        embedding = Embedding(cardinality + 1, embed_dim, name=cat_ix[i],embeddings_regularizer = l2(1e-4))(X_split[i])
        
        emb_layer.append(embedding)
    
    #Finalizing 
    emb_layer = Concatenate(axis=2)(emb_layer)
    emb_layer = Flatten(name = 'embedding')(emb_layer)
```

I get following Warning:

```
UserWarning: Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of unknown shape. This may consume a large amount of memory
 "Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of unknown shape. "
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by adding the Regularization like so:

```
embedding = Embedding(cardinality + 1, embed_dim, name=cat_ix[i])(X_split[i])
embedding.embeddings_regularizer = l2(1e-4)
```